# Why did "sudo apt-get install yum*" install 500MB of packages?

Tags: yum

I tried installing yum with following command

```
sudo apt-get install yum*
```

which took about more than 500 mb packages and a disk space of more than 1gb. 
What does this command does? and if it is wrong how to revert back these changes?

Comment: "What does this command does"... you ran a command without any idea what it does?

Comment: What was your reason to do this if you don't even know what it does? By the way, `apt-get` is a way to manage packages through the terminal and `yum` is an alternative to `apt-get`, usually found on Linux distros such as Fedora and Redhat, I believe.

Comment: @Zacharee1 [As of Fedora 22, yum has been replaced with Dnf](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum) ;)

Comment: Are you planning to install rpm based packages on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 14):

The command

```
sudo apt-get install yum*
```

installs all packages with a name containing "yu" (assuming you don't have files matching `yum*` in the folder you run the command). Most likely you don't want that.

Technically `yum*` is interpreted as as regular expression meaning "`yu` followed by zero or more instances of `m`", and that is used to do substring matching.

To revert the changes see `/var/log/apt/history.log` which packages you  with the command installed and remove them.

It's usually a very bad idea to run commands that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Florian Diesch already explained what happened when you ran the command - it installs all packages that match `yum*` regex. I'm going to explain how you can undo it.

`apt` has a log file `/var/log/apt/history.log`, where you have date and the packages that were installed. Take a look at a sample entry I have:

```
Start-Date: 2015-09-29  13:10:47
Commandline: apt-get install fail2ban
Install: python-pyinotify:amd64 (0.9.4-1build1, automatic), fail2ban:amd64 (0.8.11-1)
End-Date: 2015-09-29  13:10:54
```

It states when download began , when ended, in between it shows the exact command ran, and `Install:` shows all of the packages that were installed in the format `package-name:architecture ( version )`.

So in order to undo the effects of the command you ran, you need to select all of those packages listed, and run `sudo apt-get remove` on them.

Here is the small awk script that can give you a list of all those packages.

```
awk '/Commandline: apt-get install yum/,/End-Date/ { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/amd64/){  sub(/amd64/,""); gsub(/\:/,""); print $i} } }' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

What it does it selects all text between `Commandline: apt-get install yum` and `End-Date`, finds all fields that have `:amd64` string, and prints them out without that part. **Remember to replace amd64 with your architecture**, which you can find out with `dpkg --print-architecture`

For instance, here's a short output of my command ran for `apt-get install yakuake`

```
xieerqi:$ awk '/Commandline: apt-get install yakuake/,/End-Date/ { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/amd64/){  sub(/amd64/,""); >
libkde3support4
ntrack-module-libnl-0
libkrosscore4
libqapt2
oxygen-icon-theme
libktexteditor4
kdelibs5-data
libnepomukcleaner4
libkdeui5
libkdeclarative5
libthreadweaver4
phonon-backend-gstreamer
konsole
```

Answer (score 0):

As Florian already explained using a regex without proper understanding has negative consequences. Just because a star in one command once did what you expected doesn't mean it's always appropriate or safe syntax. Another user for example tried to install android development tools with `android*`, which left his system in an **unbootable state**. Lucky you.

**The package manager did warn you.** Here is an example from a trusty VM:

```
$ sudo apt-get install yum*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'yudit-common' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui3-min' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-prof-0.1.0-bf4c8' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'ibus-table-jyutping' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'zekr-quran-recitation-online-ayyub' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'python-yubico-tools' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yhsm-yubikey-ksm' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-doc' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libpam-yubico' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yui-compressor' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'python-yubico' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyudev' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yubikey-ksm' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'fcitx-table-jyutping' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yubikey-personalization-gui' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'compass-yui-plugin' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yum-utils' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yubiserver' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yubikey-personalization' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yum' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'fso-sounds-yue-base' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'librime-data-jyutping' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'iwyu' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui3-common' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui3-full' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yubikey-server-c' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-prof' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'python-pyudev' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-dev-0.1.0-bf4c8' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yorick-yutils' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libkeyutils-dev' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libkokyu-dev' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'quantum-plugin-ryu-agent' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libyubikey-dev' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'keyutils' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'keyutils-dbg' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui-doc' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui2' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yubikey-val' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'quantum-plugin-ryu' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'python-myghtyutils' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libauth-yubikey-decrypter-perl' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'neutron-plugin-ryu' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'xfonts-ayu' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-authn-yubikey' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'fso-sounds-yue-full' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'neutron-plugin-ryu-agent' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yui-builder' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yudit' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libyubikey0' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'yudit-doc' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-yubico' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libkokyu-6.0.3' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui3-doc' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libkeyutils1' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libjs-yui3-debug' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-dev' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libauth-yubikey-webclient-perl' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'fcitx-sayura' for regex 'yum*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-dev' instead of 'libghc-tinyurl-dev-0.1.0-bf4c8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-tinyurl-prof' instead of 'libghc-tinyurl-prof-0.1.0-bf4c8'
Note, selecting 'python-yubico' instead of 'python2.7-yubico'
Note, selecting 'zekr' instead of 'zekr-quran-recitation-online-ayyub'
libkeyutils1 is already the newest version.
libkeyutils1 set to manually installed.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  alembic ant ant-contrib ant-optional apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data
  binfmt-support ...
```

...

```
0 upgraded, 360 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 291 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1.668 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

If you don't want to install +1GB of packages, then just say no at this point and always read carefully.

It's interesting to see that yum and rpm are in the repositories, but I don't remember any site recommending managing software on Debian-based distributions this way and of course there are no repositories configured after installing yum so it can't be used as a replacement for apt. On another note Fedora switched to another tool for package management and installing foreign packages may lead to an unstable system, so I don't see why one would want to install yum.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, * stands for all (zero or more). `apt-get` means you are in a debian environment and trying to install `yum`. That is you are trying to install the whole yum package, of course it will take a lot of memory.

Comment: The command will install all packages starting with 'yum' followed by random characters. As others mentioned already - this doesn't make sense if you dont know how to use apt and yum in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

***apt-get*** is package manager for **Ubuntu** and other **Debian distributives**
***yum*** is package manager for **Red Hat, Oracle, Arch Linux** and other **Fedora distributives**.
*For example*:
**MacOS** package managers are ***Homebrew*** and ***Mac app store***
**iOS** Package manager is ***App Store***
**Android** package managers are ***Google Play Store***, ***1Mobile Market***, ***ApkPure***, ***Mobogenie***, *ect*.
*When you run that command you just installed second package manager into your system. Now you can also install **"rpm formated fedora apps"** too, just run command*:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo [repository_url]
yum install [fedora_app_name]
```

*and yes, it takes some memory. It’s large package.*